# Math.round() giving unexpected value

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to round a String value using Math.round as so:

```
String numberString = "61867345124";
int value = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(numberString));
```

but I'm getting value = 2147483647, what is going on here?

Comment: 61867345124 won't fit into a `float` without loss of precision, nor into an integer either. Use `double`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you have two issues here,

First, the output is **2147483647** because that is the max value an integer can store in Java. And your number is larger than that. You can confirm the max value for a primitive type by calling **MAX_VALUE** against its wrapper class, like below,

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

If the return value of Math.round is larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE it will return an integer having maximum value it can store,

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-float-) here,

> If the argument is positive infinity or any value greater than or
> equal to the value of Integer.MAX_VALUE, the result is equal to the
> value of Integer.MAX_VALUE.

To resolve that you can store the result in a **long** typed variable.

Second, that will still not get you desired results because **Math.round** if provided with a float input will return an integer. You need it to return a long instead which is returned if you provide it a double value.

Here are the [definitions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-), from the documentation of Math class.

```
static int  round(float a)
static long round(double a)
```

To sum up you need to both store the output as a long as well as you need to parse the string value as double, like below,

```
String numberString = "61867345124";
long value = Math.round(Double.parseDouble(numberString));
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: It's true, I learn something new every day. Thanks for sharing

Comment: Actually there are three issues here, the third being that 61867345124 won't fit into a `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using a number way larger than an integer can contain, so the output is defaulting to the maximum integer value of 2147483647. You probably want to use a long to store that value.

Comment: this answer is partially correct and doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: If the issue is not resolved then the answer is not correct.